# VLC UBUNTU external monitor automatically

Tags: vlc

I need that VLC start video at external monitor (TV) automatically every time.
X Y coordinates doesnt work. X11 config - i write :0.0 - it show on my laptop, i write :0.1 nothing happens =- no video only sound.

Answer (score 0):

Window positioning is handled by the desktop manager (ie. Gnome, Plasma, Mate, etc) not by the app.

Have a look at this similar question for a possible answer [How can I set the position that terminal opens at?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/how-can-i-set-the-position-that-terminal-opens-at)

Comment: It seems to me that this is not a very complicated issue. I need to only the video is displayed on the external monitor at full screen, and the main menu on the normal display.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using one external monitor. On ubuntu 20.04 my primal screen is the external monitor and the built-in laptop screen is also active. When i try to open a video on the external (primal) monitor, it creates an extra display that does not include control buttons like pause or stop. But when I open a video on the built-in screen, which is not primal, (primal means it increases the "Show Applications" button and that sidebar (the so-called 'dock'), it works as expected. As @GrannySez said, I guess it tries to fit the video to the screen and having trouble with that dock. So if you are using an external monitor, try to open the video on a screen with no dock.

Comment: thanks for that good editing.